# Graph complementary Isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Given G to be a k-regular graph
Can we prove that if G has n isomorphic classes, then the complement of G ̅has n isomorphic classes.

Comment: What do you mean by *$n$ isomorphic classes*?

Comment: Do you mean n members of its isomorphism class https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_class ?

Comment: @gilleain yeah I guess, thought they have the same meaning